# Print file to html without quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

i am using rails 4,
I am trying to read a file a print it to an html page as it, i print it using partial view.
the way i am using it is:
in the controller:

```
@task_schema = IO.read("{ENV["HOME"]}/lib/task_templates/task")
```

And in the partial view:

```
$('form').jsonForm(<%= @task_schema %>)
```

the problem is that in the html page, i see this string with quotes in it.
for example, if @task_schema="A B C", in the html i see it also as "ABC", with the quotes as well. How can i print it as is, without the quotes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect it to be ABC, as your variable have "ABC" it is printing as "ABC". How is the data stored in the file, I think you should either change it in the file or in the code snippet where you are parsing the file data.

Comment: The file contains a lot of data, but without quotes in the beginning, for the example the file contains ABC, but the html shows "ABC"

Comment: ohh, I think jsonForm can be culprit.